# Vagrant private network does not work when host machine connected to VPN

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtual-machine, vpn

I'm working with Vagrant and VirtualBox and sharing a folder between my host computer and the guest VM using NFS and a private network:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = '2'
Vagrant.require_version '>= 1.8.4'

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  ...

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: '10.0.2.15'
  config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', type: 'nfs'

  ...
end
```

When my host machine is connected to my work's VPN (SonicWALL Mobile Connect), I cannot start the VM or access it without it hanging. I assume this is because the VPN is sending **all** network traffic over the VPN, including my private network traffic.

It would be nice if I could configure the VPN to exclude IP ranges from going over the VPN, but that does not appear to be the case.

Is there any recourse here? If I can't use the virtual machine while connected to the VPN, it significantly reduces the usefulness =/

EDIT: I've also tried with 192.168.0.x which I've confirmed is a range NOT used by other devices on the network.

Comment: did you try with another IP address such as `192.168.X.X` ?

Comment: Yes, same behavior